# Finding metadata about File Geodatabase using ESRIs File Geodatabase API?

Tags: file-geodatabase, file-geodatabase-api

I'm using these DLLs and I'm very new to GIS and Geodatabase files in general.

I'm just curious if I can get a list of the tables and some more in depth documentation/examples if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155310/can-i-find-metadata-about-a-file-geodatabase-using-esris-file-geodatabase-api#comment229085_155310):

> The documentation shows both can be obtained by requests against the
>   Geodatabase object (Geodatabase::GetChildDatasets &
>   Geodatabase::GetDatasetDocumentation, respectively). The documentation
>   is what it is; I doubt anyone has written a book about FGDB API.

and again [by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155310/can-i-find-metadata-about-a-file-geodatabase-using-esris-file-geodatabase-api#comment229087_155310):

> FileGDB_API_VS2010_1_4/doc/index.html I believe you can use an empty
>   string or a "/" to fetch the top-level objects (simple feature classes
>   outside feature datasets, plus the list of container objects).